# Properites with image links are undefined in vue.js data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, undefined, slim, axios

I have a json array that comes from server, which looks like this:

```
[{
  "extension": ".jpeg",
  "height": 1080,
  "id": 2640878,
  "metadataOnly": true,
  "name": "84b3250b27f659272161f66ed16e9512.jpeg",
  "originalPost": "https://example.com",
  "orignalImage": "https://example.com/image.jpeg",
  "orignalThumbnail": "https://example.com/image_preview.jpeg",
  "score": 1,
  "width": 1920
}, ... (other similiar objects)]
```

This json is requested from server with axios and set to a data property in my Vue instance:

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: "div#images-list",
    data: {
        images: []
    },

    mounted() {
        axios.get("/get_images").then(response => {
            this.images = response.data;
        })
    }
});
```

This mounts it to the specified block and calls mounted, axios gets the json array, and if a print it *without* assigning to `this.images`, it prints alright and i see all the fields. But after i assign it to `this.images`, fields that contain images (`originalImage` and `originalThumbnail`) become undefined when i try to print them from javascript console. All other fields work and print their values. Finally, here's HTML (in ruby's slim format):

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"
    script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"
    script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"
  body
    div#images-list
      div v-for="image in images" v-bind:key="image.id"
        a v-bind:href="image.originalImage"
          | {{ image.name }}

    script src="/js/index.js"
```

This produces a page of `a` elements with image names (from `image.name`) but without the href attribute (because links are somehow undefined). Any idea about why fields with image links become undefined (but other links do not, e.g. `originalPost`) and how to fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify: how does the code look like when you _do not_ assign a value to images and see everything is alright. I mean, how does the working version of it look like?

Comment: @vahdet same thing, but without `this.images = response.data;`. If i print the value with `console.log` i get what you see in the JSON example. The problem is then i can't put it into the page, because Vue does not know about it.

Comment: Ok then, did you try `created` lifecycle hook instead of `mounted`? `mounted` may be far too late for an async call.

Comment: I previously tried to do it in `window.onload` and got the same behaviour there. `created` didn't do anything either.

Comment: Nothing in your code here explains that behavior.

Comment: Well that's the whole code, really. It's so strange, I don't even know why this could happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. Uh. It was a typo. It isn't `original`, it is `orignal`. And nobody noticed.